# OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade) is not deleting entity entry, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have problem with deleting entity with foreign key. This is my Game-info class :

```
public class Game_info
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Kod Code { get; set; }
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public string Player_name { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my Kod class

```
public class Kod
{
    public long KodId { get; set; }
    public string FirstColor { get; set; }
    public string SecondColor { get; set; }
    public string ThirdColor { get; set; }
    public string FourthColor{ get; set;}
}
```

When I'm updating Game_info object with setting new Kod it's working properly, Kod is changing in database but when I'm deleting Game_info object from database, the Kod entry leaves in database

```
        //This working ok
        var poz = _context.Game_Info.SingleOrDefault(m => m.SessionID == sessionID);
        poz.Code.FirstColor = c1; poz.Code.SecondColor = c2; poz.Code.ThirdColor = c3; 
        poz.Code.FourthColor = c4;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // This is not working 
        var game = _context.Game_Info.Include(m=> m.Code).First(m => m.SessionID == SessionID);
        _context.Game_info.Remove(game);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

I was trying with Include, I have delete rule in database properties, database model looks like below (there is OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade rule) so I don't know what's wrong. On default in database model was .WithMany() I don't know why, because Game_info can have one "Kod" only so I changed it on .WithOne() but problem is still there.
[image]

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("Mastermind.Models.Game_info", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Mastermind.Models.Kod", "Code")
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey("CodeKodId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
                    b.Navigation("Code");
```

Comment: Cascade delete works in the opposite direction (principal -> dependent). The entity with FK (in your case `Game_info`) is always the *dependent*. See [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) documentation topic.

Comment: Yes, you right, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Like Ivan Stoev said it was wrong direction, I changed model of class :

```
 public class Game_info
{
    public long Game_infoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Kod Code { get; set; }
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public string Player_name { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class Kod
{
    public long KodId { get; set; }
    public string FirstColor { get; set; }
    public string SecondColor { get; set; }
    public string ThirdColor { get; set; }
    public string FourthColor{ get; set;}

    public long Game_infoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Game_info Game { get; set; }
```

}

and now it's working properly.